# Futur perfect Tense

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, future-perfect

Is this sentence grammatical and idiomatic?

- I **will** **already** **have eaten** *when* you **get back**.

To say that when .. ,let's say Mary, come back home, I will have already finished eating, I mean I will already have eaten.

Many thanks :-)

Comment: Yes, it’s a good sentence.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about it as it stands, but I think that a native speaker might say "I will have eaten *by the time* you get back". However "I will eat when you get back" is idiomatic. "When" refers  specifically to a moment in time, and seems less appropriate to describe something that could have taken place at any prior time - if you understand me.